# Switch tab bar include sending data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

How can i change the tab bar? i know this post seems duplicate but i cant find any exist question that similar to me. Right now my current

> selectedIndex = 0

so i want to make it go to tab number 3 which is

> selectedIndex = 2

But i also want to send data from currentView to nextView. if i using push+selectedindex it will go to tab 3 but push the view from selectedindex = 0, and there is no data send to selectedIndex = 2
My current code

```
func redeemBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let selectedRedeemBtnInfo = fixedGridInfo[sender.tag] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        sender.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FlightExploration", bundle: nil)
        let searchFlightVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchFlightVC") as! SearchFlightViewController

        var newFlightType = String()

        if "\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["FlightType"]!)" == "Return" {
            newFlightType = "Round"
        } else {
            newFlightType = "One"
        }

        searchFlightVC.flightType = newFlightType
        searchFlightVC.fromHome = true
        searchFlightVC.departure = "\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["Departure"]!) (\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["DepartureCityCode"]!)"
        searchFlightVC.arrival = "\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["Destination"]!) (\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["DestinationCityCode"]!)"
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchFlightVC, animated: true)
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
    }
```

Comment: You want to push `searchFlightVC` in tab 3's Navigation right?

Comment: When you click on some action on tab 0, the tab should change to 2 with some data being sent?

Comment: @NiravD sort of, as long as i able to change the selected tab 3's include all those data. and tab 1's stay on the same view

Comment: @Mr.Bista yes, mate!

Comment: @AyusSalleh Then you need to set `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2` first and then you need to push the ViewController from that tab 3's navigations.

Comment: @NiravD understood, but how can i change tab without push from tab 1's while the data is captured in tab 1's.

Comment: @AyusSalleh Is your 3rd tab's ViewController also embeded with NavigationController?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to send the data to that UIViewController which is a ViewController of UITabBarController

```
    var yourViewController : TempViewController
    if let arrController = tabBarController?.viewControllers {
        for vc in arrController {
            if vc is TempViewController {
                yourViewController = vc as! TempViewController
            }
        }
    }

    yourViewController.yourData = dataToPass
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from Rajat's answer seems helped me to solved the issue

```
func redeemBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let selectedRedeemBtnInfo = fixedGridInfo[sender.tag] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        sender.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true

        var newFlightType = String()

        if "\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["FlightType"]!)" == "Return" {
            newFlightType = "Round"
        } else {
            newFlightType = "One"
        }

        if let arrController = tabBarController?.viewControllers {
            for vc in arrController {
                if vc.childViewControllers[0] is SearchFlightViewController {
                    let displayViewController = vc.childViewControllers[0] as! SearchFlightViewController
                    let _ = displayViewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                    //displayViewController.flightType = newFlightType
                    displayViewController.flightTypeFromHome = newFlightType
                    displayViewController.fromHome = true
                    displayViewController.departure = "\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["Departure"]!) (\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["DepartureCityCode"]!)"
                    displayViewController.arrival = "\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["Destination"]!) (\(selectedRedeemBtnInfo["DestinationCityCode"]!)"
                    displayViewController.flightType = "Round"

                    displayViewController.departureDateLbl = "Select One"
                    displayViewController.passenger = "1 Adult"
                    displayViewController.adultCount = 1
                    displayViewController.childCount = Int()
                    displayViewController.infantCount = Int()
                    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
                    tabBarController?.tabBar((tabBarController?.tabBar)!, didSelect: (tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2])!)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rajat's answer Switch Tab Bar and Pass data, in **Swift 4.2, iOS 11** need some changes to be done:

```
func switchToTab2(){}
    var yourViewController = MyTab2ViewController()
    if let arrController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
        for vc in arrController {
            if vc is MyTab2ViewController {
                yourViewController = vc as! MyTab2ViewController
                yourViewController.productTitle = "Title"
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 /// tabs start from 0
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

***MyTab2ViewController*** is your viewcontroller connected to tab bar with index 1. (first tab index: 0)